# ¿Son buenas practicas tener una función dentro de una función pública?

Tags: php, laravel, funciones

Tengo la siguiente función pública en mi controlador en esta función publica he escrito otra función que convierte los $request que me llegan en minusculas y agregar snake case, mi pregunta es ¿Son buenas practicas tener esta función dentro de mi función publica?

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  
        function convertSnake($data) {             
            
            $snake_case = str_replace(" ", "_", strtolower($data));
            
            return $snake_case;        
        }

     ............ Más código ...........   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución a pesar de *funcionar* **considero** no es la óptima, analiza esta pregunta:

¿Qué pasaría si necesitas después esa función de conversión en otra ubicación que no es la función `score`?

Dado lo anterior, considera tener centralizados estos métodos de tal manera que los puedas invocar de manera posterior.

Por otro lado tampoco necesitas (*aunque no es incorrecto*) de las funciones nativas del lenguaje para solventar lo que buscas, el framework [dispone de varios *helpers*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#strings-method-list) que te simplifican el trabajo.

Logrando tener una solución tan *simple* como esto:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

Str::lower(Str::replace(" ", "_", $data));
```

> Con lo anterior puedes comprobar que ese método **ni siquiera es necesario**

Comment: Con lo anterior puedes comprobar que ese método **ni siquiera es necesario.**

Answer (score 1):

no es lo mas optimo si define una función F1 dentro de otra función F2 solo lo puede llama dentro de la función F1 , hay caso especiales que toca llama la misma función en otro métodos o controladores, por ejemplo calcula el IVA de un producto o calcula una serie de operaciones complejas

le voy a demostrar como se deber realiza los llamados de otras funciones

creamos un archivo en ImportaSolicitudedItem.php
en app\Imports\ImportaSolicitudedItem.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;

class ImportaSolicitudedItem
{

    public function estado($suma1, $suma2)
    {

        return ($suma1 + $suma2);
    }
}
```

en el controlador vamos a importa el archivo

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use View;
use App\User;
use App\Imports\ImportaSolicitudedItem;

class SolicitudItemController extends Controller{
    

     public function procesaArchivos(Request $request, $input_id_model){
             //llamamos el controlaror 
             $fu = new ImportaSolicitudedItem();
             $suma2 = 4;
             $suma1 = 10;
             $resulado = $fu->estado($suma1, $suma2);
             var_dump($resulado);//retorna 14

             // si desea llama una funcion dentro del controlador
             $resultado = $this->resta(8,9);
             var_dump($resulado);
      }
      public function resta($resta1,$resta2){
           return ($resta1-$resta2);
      }


}
```